# Why "TypeError: express.Router is not a function"

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to make a login app with nodejs express.
However after I run it. it shows TypeError: express.Router is not a function.
My express is the latest version4.13.4. Can anyone help me?Here is the code.

```
var User = require('../modules/user');
var config = require('../../config');

var secretKey = config.secretKey;

module.exports = function(app,express){
    var api = express.Router;
    api.post('/signup', function(req,res){
        var user = new User({
            name: req.body.name,
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        });

        user.save(function(err){
            if(err){
                res.send(err);
                return;
            }

            res.json({ message: 'user has been created'});
        })
    });

    return api;
};
```

Comment: Aren't you forgeting to include the express library?

Comment: you should be calling `Router()` method to get a new router instance. But would you mind to post the code of the module which imports this?

Answer (score 5):

It should be `var api = express.Router();`

Answer (score 4):

I can't see the require to include the express library.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

Also remember to make

> $ npm install express --save

To install it.

Here is the reference

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

http://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Answer (score 2):

var api = express.Router();

or try this code :

```
var router = require('express').Router(),
    User = require('../modules/user'),
    config = require('../../config');

router
    .post('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
        var user = new User(req.body);    

        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            else res.json({message: 'user has been created'});
        })

    });

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to require the express module, before calling the Router method, with this you can add more HTTP method to "/signup" route.

```
var express = require('express');    
var User = require('../modules/user');
var config = require('../../config');
var api = express.Router();
var secretKey = config.secretKey;

module.exports = function(api) {
  api.route('/signup')
   .post(function(req, res) {
     var user = new User({
       name: req.body.name,
       username: req.body.username,
       password: req.body.password
     });

     user.save(function(err) {
      if (err) res.send(err);

      res.json({ message: 'user has been created'});
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send('Course Controller');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What are the benefits of this approach over the preexisting solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding require('http') or require('https') as the first require statement.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem of `var express = express()` returning the error: not a function.  After some spelunking in the express directories, I saw that the sample code required http or https first.  So, add one (perhaps both) as first (and or second) file imports.

Answer (score -1):

write npm i express -s

I've tried and it's working for me